# How do i take a list and turn all of the items in it and seperate them into there own string?

Tags: python

I want the list items to be separated into their own strings.
It would be something like this.

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

---------?---------

```
string1 = 'a'
string2 = 'b'
string3 = 'c'
```

Comment: why would you do that? creating variables dynamically is not recommended, while using a list is the better option, which seems you are already using

Comment: look here: [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed number of variables you may try this:

```
[string1, string2, string3] = ['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: `string1, string2, string3 = ['1', '2', '3']` would be better. Your version is also creating a list object which will then be immediately discarded.